# Is there a way for mysql field value to be constantly updated based on another field value?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a field "date_added", where it stores the date when an item has been added to stock. Additionally, I want another field "days_on_shelf", where it shows the amount of days the item is on the shelf. Is there a way that I can use the current date and the date added to calculate the value of the days_on_shelf field? I also want it to be constantly updated as the days go by to increment the days.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a trigger

See more at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

For the days on shelf field you can just use a generated field

Comment: I was about to post this link: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php#CMT. Alternatively, run a Cronjob that updates the field daily.

Comment: No, you cannot use triggers for this question as triggers are triggered by a data manilulation query, while in the question date added field does not change.

Comment: @Shadow the trigger would be (I'm quoting here) "when an item has been added to stock".

Comment: That would calculate the difference  (days on shelf) only once, when the record is inserted. It would not cslculste the difference the next day or any other following day.

Comment: @Shadow! Yeah! You are right! I guess since they already have (through the trigger) the "date_added" field, then they should use a generated field that just subtracts the current date from the dated_added and they would have the "days_on_shelf" info. I'll update my original answer

Comment: Generated columns can only use static functions. Curdate and now are not static functions, so your second idea would not work either.